# filter not working while backspace key press in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very new to the reactjs. I am trying to apply filters on array of object which working fine firstly, but problem arises when I press backspace key the list not get updated as per search string. [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-tu-rlxpj?file=/src/App.js)  is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies in the asynchronous nature of setState function. In your filter method, you expect that it was already updated two lines before, but it can be still in the process of updating. Anyway, isn't it easier to filter the original list?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(search === ''){
      setbllist(arr);
    }
    if(search !== ''){
      setbllist(arr.filter(bl => {
        let name = bl.name.toLowerCase();
        return name.includes(search.toLowerCase())        
      }));
    }
  },[search])
```